# Blade Server Networking Connectivity Solution

Tags: networking, storage-area-network, datacenter, fibre-channel, blade-server

We are looking at purchasing 4 of the Dell M1000e Blade Chassis', along with 16x Half Height Servers in each. For our LAN Connection, we are looking at 2x MXL 10/40 GbE IO's per Chassis. From my understanding, each side of the chassis can be daisy chained together, so that there are two groups, each with 4 IO's (1 from each Chassis), using 4 of the available 6 external ports. This would then leave the remaining 2 ports on each IO to go to the network aggregation/core layer.

We are also looking at using a FC SAN, potentially the Dell SC9000. For this, we are looking at using the M6505. The SAN itself will likely connect to a separate FC Switch. In terms of the FC IO's in the back of the chassis, should they also be daisy chained together, much like the MXL, or should each external port simply connect directly to the FC Switch used for the SAN to connect to?

Thanks